# Same code for multiple frames

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have 3 frames with a text box, what I'm trying to do is to put a text in it via code, so that it will show up in every frame, but with this code all I get is the text showing up only in the first frame and only once.

```
this.movie_clip.text1.text = "PROVA";
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening, because you have textbox in all three KEYFRAMES, so Flash treats them as three different textboxes. Create new layer with only textbox on it and one keyframe on 1st frame and two normal frames (double press F5 if I remember well).

Comment: Thanks, this avoid me a lot of pain!